# What are these engineers doing sitting on a large format drawing of B-47s aircraft?

Tags: military, strategic-bomber

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/30646/12102) about solid-jet-assisted takeoff links to the page [B-47 Jet-Assisted Take Off (JATO)](http://heroicrelics.org/info/b-47/b-47-jato.html). An image there took me to [a collection of historical aviation images](http://images.google.com/hosted/life/18cf148b719c6554.html), apparently from a LIFE Magazine archive.

Browsing there led me to the image below, of what looks like several aviation engineers sitting on *a very large format drawing* of a B-47 aircraft and its major components.

A reverse image search leads mostly to sites written in Russian, which I can't read.

Does anyone recognize what's actually happening here? It's not scene one would normally see these days.

[image: LIFE magazine B-47 Stratojet Bomber image]

source: http://images.google.com/hosted/life/2ce91e390933d837.html

> B-47 Stratojet Bomber, Date taken: September 9, 1950 Photographer: Howard Sochurek

Comment: It's still a valuable exercise to work with [scale models](http://www.modelbuilders.net/blog/bid/135846/Plant-layout-models-can-save-time-and-money) to plan out large processes like aircraft production. 3D printing has only made that even easier.

Comment: Thanks man for the picture , it will be on my wall :)

Comment: Online translators are actually pretty decent the next time you are stuck like this.

Comment: @Infiltrator depending on the particular language, your milage may vary, and without a native speaker to review the on-line translation, how can one identify the  inevitable errors and mistranslations?

Comment: @uhoh: It is not a solution, of course.  I just mean that it can be the first tool for which you reach.

Comment: @AliErdem Dostum I think it is a nice resim and it is good to have this aviation tutkusu too.

Comment: @F.Bek is it your first time running into someone from your country in internet :) why don't we be friends btw, we can share some beer or tea and talk about Kelly Johnson

Comment: They appear to be squatting or leaning over, not sitting.

Comment: @jpmc26  - The guy at the top left (white shirt=supervisor) seems to be grasping his temple and saying *"Oh, crap... they did it just like I told them to - I'm going to loose my job!"*

Comment: @jwzumwalt I was going to suggest it's a variant of Twister played only by aerospace engineers ...

Comment: @AliErdem I would love to talk about aviation and beer sounds amazing. I have Linkedin profile linked to my stackexchange account. Lets connect ! Then I will delete these funny comments.

Comment: related in an aesthetic way: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11145/7118

Answer (score 83, accepted):

As commented by Anilv, they are examining a factory production layout/plan. They most likely are attempting to resolve a production or supply problem, though as Anilv suggests, they may also be planning the factory layout.

Listed below is an example of the B-17 Flying Fortress Factory Production Layout used by Boeing in WWII. Note the arrows which show the production procession and parts/sub-assembly entry and exit.

[image]
[Source - Boeing](http://www.boeingimages.com/archive/B-17%20Flying%20Fortress%20Factory%20Production%20Layout-2F3XC5JZX56.html)

Comment: Yes, I can immediately understand now, this makes a lot of sense, thank you!

Comment: Those look like B-29's.

Comment: I think Boeing knows what their own airplanes look like, the picture was from their web site? They probably were not interested in a scientifically accurate silhouette.

Comment: They are indeed B-29's, look at the trailing edge of the wings, the inner engine nacelles have a fillet that extends beyond the trailing edge of the wing on the B-29, the B-17 does not. The wings are narrower on the B-29, too. And even the manufacturer can make a mistake and mislabel the image.

Comment: Good answer, but as to what they're doing (planning or troubleshooting something), we should realize that they may simply be _posing for a good photo._ :)

Comment: @Davidw - I think artistic license was used. I admit the art department used B-29 for the B-17 but the nose and cowl of a B-29 are longer. It looks like they  took a B-29 silhouette and scaled it for a B-17. If you look at the top right compared to the bottom right, the tip profile is significantly different in width. The trailing edge wing of a B-29 is nearly straight horizontally while the B-17 is noticeably tapered; the silhouette is half way in-between. In war, you grab what ever will get through the day and run with it. It looks like someone took their scissors and said "good enough".

Comment: @TypeIA - I thought they were from New York and were pitching pennies. Shows what I know...

Answer (score 29):

Just to confirm, [one of the sites](http://otvet.in/science_tech/4160-bolshoy-pazzl-ssha-1951-god.html) you mentioned says:

> Планирование производства бомбардировщиков B–47 на заводе ВВС США №6.
>   Завод ВВС США №6, был построен в 1942–1943 годах в небольшом городке Мариетта, штат Джорджия, для Bell corporation, и предназначался для выпуска бомбардировщиков B–29.
>
> Завод до сих пор остается одним из крупнейших зданий в мире, его площадь под одной крышей составляет 390200 м2.
>   После войны завод был закрыт, но в 50-х годах открыт вновь, вначале для ремонта и модернизации бомбардировщиков B–50, а затем для производства B–47 силами компании Lockheed Martin.
>
> Завод работает и в настоящее время, на нем производится ремонт и обслуживание самолетов ВВС США, в том числе Lockheed/Boeing F-22 Raptor.

That translates to (emphasis mine):

> **Planning the production of B-47 bombers at the US Air Force plant No. 6.**
>   US Air Force No. 6, was built in 1942-1943 in the small town of Marietta, Georgia, for Bell corporation, and was intended for the production of B-29 bombers.
>   The plant still remains one of the largest buildings in the world, its area under one roof is 390,200 m².
>
> After the war, the plant was closed, but in the 1950s it was reopened, first to repair and modernize the B-50 bombers, and then to manufacture the B-47 by Lockheed Martin.
>
> The plant is currently in operation and repairing and servicing the US Air Force aircraft, including Lockheed / Boeing F-22 Raptor.

Comment: Thank you for this! It seems to be quite informative.

Comment: @uhoh you can use Google Translate on web pages in languages you can't read, it's not perfect but it gives you an idea of what it's about.